# How to show and hide list items(li) elements inside unordered list(ul) using jquery(preferably)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Unordered list in HTML file:

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="authorization">
          <li class="nav-item" class="authorizationLink">
            <a class="nav-link" href="registration.html">Registration</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" class="authorizationLink">
            <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="usernameDropdown" style="display: none">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
              </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <button id="someButton">button</button>
```

I want to hide the list items with *class="authorizationLink"* and to show the list item with *id="navbarDropdown"* on the click of a button. I have tried this so far:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#someButton").click(function() {
            $(".authorizationLink").hide();
            $("#usernameDropdown").show();
        })
    }
```

I have tried several more things, with one solution working sometimes, but not working most of the time. Is there a way for this to work using jquery? Maybe with some css trick or something else?

Comment: I don't see an element with the id `someButton`...?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet, so we easily can run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML elements can only have one `class` attribute. If there are more classes, combine them in the same String separated by spaces. Also, you need a endbracket for the jQuery `$(document).ready()`

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="authorization">
          <li class="nav-item authorizationLink">
            <a class="nav-link" href="registration.html">Registration</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item authorizationLink">
            <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="usernameDropdown" style="display: none">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
              </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <button id="someButton">button</button>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#someButton").click(function() {
            $(".authorizationLink").hide();
            $("#usernameDropdown").show();
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Alright, I made these changes, and it worked the first time I runned it, but after that it just leaves the two links to be. So something else is wrong in my project. Thanks anyway for clearing this up.

Comment: @nskrobonja95 No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is fine, you just have some syntax errors.

- Change `class="nav-item" class="authorizationLink"` to `class="nav-item authorizationLink"`. **You should only have one `class` attribute per element.**
- You're missing a `)` at the end of your jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Here, just change how you have set the class attribute. Instead of having 2 class attributes, combine the value into same string.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#someButton").click(function() {
            $(".authorizationLink").hide();
            $("#usernameDropdown").show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="authorization">
          <li class="nav-item authorizationLink">
            <a class="nav-link" href="registration.html">Registration</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item authorizationLink">
            <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="usernameDropdown" style="display: none">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
              </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <button id="someButton">button</button>
```